# No way of having Internet Diagnostics on MacBook Pro 16

Tags: hardware, apple-diagnostics

I'd like to run Internet Diagnostics on my MacBook Pro 16 2019, but for reasons that puzzle me, I really can't. When I shutdown, press the power button and hold the D (or even Option D) key nothing happens, that is the system boots in the usual way.

I'm running without devices attached, except for the power cord. I suppose that Internet Diagnostics would detect available WiFi and then ask for a password (as I saw it on other macs).

Thanks.

PS I must say that I've also run the procedures to reset SMC and NVRAM and I'm doubtful whether something happened.

Comment: Precisely which Macbook Pro & OS?

Comment: MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)

Comment: Check https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208198

Answer (score 1):

After a number of attempts to reset the various resettable things, there has been no way to run diagnostics locally, but Option-D started diagnostics remotely, connecting to the WiFi.